# C++ Passing data to Form from outside

Tags: c++, forms

I'm starting my journey with C++ and i need help with passing data to my forms objects.
I wrote simple bot (dll project) which is injected into game and doing some stuff. Now i want to add GUI for it. So i added Forms to my project. All working well but i dont know how to pass data into my active form window from outside of form class.
For example. I have a function that receives data from game and i want to pass them to my datagridview. I tried something like that:
In Forms class i added a method to fill datagridview:

```
 void sendToGridView(char* data,PacketDirection direction)
        {

            this->dataGridView1->Rows->Add(PrintPacket(data, direction));
        }
```

In my function (outside of Form class) i try to call this method:

```
    MainForm mf;
    mf.sendToGridView(lpMsg, Recv);
```

but it doesent work
Big THX for any tips, hints and sugestions.

Answer (score 0):

I temporary resolved this issue by creating class

```
ref class FormCaller
{
public:
    static MainForm^ form;
};
```

And on the Form side public getters and setters 
example of calling from functions:

```
FormCaller::form->sendToGridView(packet, Send);
```